# cordova ios WKWebView upgrade - errors when showing some images

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, wkwebview

I'm working on an app with Ionic 1 and AngularJS 1.5

I was told that I need to upgrade my ios to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView:
https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/?utm_campaign=enterprise&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=85128961&_hsenc=p2ANqtz--vsf3kcg7MssMWwjv2_GpHmVbzN23_5fXDfKT0E6OileYraLWs9btGPqWUcq5mzTKCtKwXGqO35V3SnInjypj4uqSBRg&_hsmi=85128961

Here is my setup:

```
cordova-android 8.1.0
cordova-ios 5.1.0
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3
cordova 8.1.2
ionic 5.4.16
node 10.19.0
iOS 13 iPhone 11 Pro Max

Error:

unsafe:ionic://localhost/img/white/activities.svg
An error occurred while trying to load the resource
```

I have tried the suggestion here with the sanitize but it doesn't seem to work for me:
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/284

How can I get my images to show?

Comment: I am also planning to migrate the Angular cordova iOS app ( not ionic ) to WKWebView. Just wondering what were the first step that you took.

Comment: Will totally appreciate it if you can point out what should I do first to kick things started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there was a problem with my code and yes, the suggestion here does work:
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/284

```
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob|ionic):|data:image\//);
```

Now all my images show.