# Ionic v1 src=unsafe for all images with latest Cordova-ios@5.1.1

Tags: ios, image, cordova, ionic-framework

Just built a new Mac cordova/ionic envorinoment with all the latest and greatest versions of Cordova, Node, etc - but still running an Ionic v1 project.  My app is compiling and deploying to devices but all my images are broken and the source code shows like:

```
<img class="loading" ng-src="img/ajax_loading.gif"src="unsafe:ionic://myApp/img/ajax_loading.gif">
```

Old Mac: Cordova@9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) with cordova-ios@5.0.1
New Mac: Cordova@9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) with cordova-ios@5.1.1

Looks like something changed between 5.0.1 and 5.1.1 - but I don't know what.  Is there a plugin to remedy this or how do I go about fixing this.  I have lots of images in my app that are all broken.

Comment: ...or I am wondering if this is an issue with the latest Xcode 11.5?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and resolved it by following this answer: [cordova ios WKWebView upgrade - errors when showing some images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934961/cordova-ios-wkwebview-upgrade-errors-when-showing-some-images)

Basically it stems from WkWebView being less permissive than the UIWebView from whence you came.

I had to add the following config block to my app.js:

```
.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob|ionic):|data:image/);
}
```

If you discover as I did, that some internal hrefs no longer work, add this line  to the config block as well:

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|ionic|tel|mailto):/);
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issues and the solution to load images (using "imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist") worked perfectly - thanks a lot! My problem now is with the href links, that are not opening. I tried the suggested solution, with "aHrefSanitizationWhitelist", but the problem still happens (and there are no errors on the console). Any ideas? Maybe I'm missing something (I think that could be a configuration in config.xml file).